# How to automatically make Blender choose random colors for your render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, color

[image: This is one of the colors.]

I want to make this render but don't know which color to use for the logo. How to make Blender render with random colors for me to then check and use the best one.

Answer (score 3):

While there's no way to have blender check and choose the best color for you, as that is quite subjective, it is possible to set the color to change every frame and to render an animation of those multiple different colored frames.

To do so, first head over to your material tab, and select the shader currently applied to your text object. Now press Shift+A and create a color ramp node, and a value node. Then plug the Value into the Fac of the color ramp. Then plug the color into your principled BSDF or wherever you need it to be. Then go to the first frame of your timeline, put your mouse over the value nodes number, and press I to keyframe it. Go to a different frame in your timeline set the value of the node to 1 and then press I on it again. Now when you play your animation the value node will change from 0 to 1 and control the color ramps output color.

Now just input the colors you want into your color ramp, go to the render tab, turn down the output resolution, and turn on render regions and make them scaled down to just cover the relevant parts of the scene. Render an image sequence to a folder, and then you can go through and see a ton of different color options to use.

[image]